# Класс с известными данными

Tags: java, android

Ребята, помогите нубу
Нужно получить такое обращение

```
String s = myColor.green.name;  //"Зеленый"
int i = myColor.green.code;     //123
String s2 = myColor.red.name;   //"Красный"
int i2 = myColor.red.code;      //234
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как описать такой класс, чтобы в нем было несколько подклассов (green, red, ..) с одинаковыми полями (name, code, id, ..)

Повсякому пробовал, не получается.

PS: Может это не классы, а как-нибудь подругому называется. Данные ведь сразу известны

Comment: 1) создаем класс `Color` с нужными параметрами (типа `name`/`code`/etc) 2) создаем класс `Palette`, у которого есть поля `green`/`red`/etc нашего класса `Color`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите генерируемый класс android.R, похоже там такая же структура, как вам нужна. Внутри класса есть статические классы, а внутри них статические поля, к которым можно обращаться из любого класса, например, как Color.green.name

```
public class Color{
    public static class green {
        public static final String name = "Зелёный";
        public static final int code = 0x00FF00;
    }

    public static class red {
        public static final String name = "Красный";
        public static final int code = 0xFF0000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Извините, протупил, делюсь

```
//Объявление класса
    static class MyColorList {
        class MyColor {
            String name;
            int code, id;
            MyColor(String name, int code, int id) {
                this.name = name;
                this.code = code;
                this.id = id;
            }
        }
        public final MyColor Green = new MyColor("Зеленый", 1, 0);
        public final MyColor Red = new MyColor("Красный", 2, 1);
    }
//объявление статичной переменной, далее к ней можно обратиться в любом коде
    public static MyColorList myColor = new MyColorList();

//обращение
String greenTitle = myColor.Green.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

А я всё чаще замечаю, как много здесь велосипедистов..)
Ну для кого придумали перечисления-то, люди?)
ТС, держи невелосипедный вариант:

```
public enum MyColor {
    GREEN {
        public String getName() { return "Зелёный"; }
        public int getCode() { return 123; }
    },

    RED {
        public String getName() { return "Красный"; }
        public int getCode() { return 234; }
    };

    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract int getCode();
}
```

Обращаться как `MyColor.GREEN.getCode();`